# Datepickers With Multifunction

Tags: jquery, date, math, calendar, calculated-field

I managed to get this to run but only up-to a point. What I'm trying to do is the following:

There are 2 datepickers and one text field.

1. Once date1 is selected, will then auto-generate date2 with a "future date" say... 6, 12, 24, 36 month.
2. Based on the info in those two date fields, I need to calculate the remaining days between date1 and date2.

e.g. DATE1 (06/01/2012) -> DATE2 Gets Date from DATE1 and ADDS 12 OR 24. (06/01/2013) -> DAYS (365)

Below is the code in case someone can help out. Thanks!

```
$(function() {
$("#dop").datepicker
    ({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 12);
        $("#wed").datepicker("setDate", date);
        if ($('#dop') && $('#wed')) {
        $("#days").val($("#dop").getTime() - $("#wed").getTime() / 86400000);
        }
    }
});
$("#wed").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",  
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/TCXcX/332/

Comment: Ran out of time last evening and wasn't able to complete the example code. Finished it this morning. Trust it is what you require. The trick, as seen at top of my answer, is to turn the date STRING back into a date OBJECT, so that you can perform the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only got so far before must stop (time). Here's where I got to, perhaps it will help.

You must turn your field values back into dates, as so:

```
            var t1 = $("#dop").val();
            var t1d = new Date(t1);
```

[Fully working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2j2rn/2/)

---

Finished example. If this doesn't do what you want, please respond with details:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dop").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 12);
            $("#wed").datepicker("setDate", date);
            if ($('#dop') && $('#wed')) {
                var t1 = $("#dop").val();
                //alert(t1);
                var t1d = new Date(t1);
                //alert(t1d);
                var t2 = $("#wed").val();
                var t2d = new Date(t2);
                var diff = (t2d - t1d)/86400000;
                //alert(diff);
                $('#days').val(diff);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#wed").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",  
    });
```

### });

[Here's another jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2j2rn/4/) where the number of months to add is stored in a hidden input field.

Comment: Gib, One more question if you don't mind. Date1->Date2=Days works awesome. I try to extend it a bit for when someone change Date2 say...a day or two, then Days field will update and increase the days. Although, it "works" the Days field gets increase not by 1 day but by 30. Ideas?